# Manipulating a Google Doc outline using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is there a way to use a Google App Script to remove an item in the document outline (the outline that appears when you select View->Show Document Outline in the top menu)? I have a script that adds several H3 headers, and I don't want those headers to appear in my outline.

Comment: Why would you use the h3 setting on lines if you don't want those lines to appear in the document outline? That's the point of header formatting.

Comment: I want them to be headings, but I only want two levels of headings to appear in my outline. I suppose I could format the text manually, but then you lose benefits like being able to change the formatting on all of them at once.